# Make other VMs show in Network on windows server in Azure

Tags: networking, sql-server, virtual-machines, azure

I'm deploying a desktop app that connects to a remote database.  standard 2-tier setup, but it's not a web app.  People will log in via RemoteApp.  But I'm having trouble getting the app instances in RemoteApp to connect to the server.

There are 2 Azure VMs, each with windows 2008 R2.  I read that if you put them in the same service, I wouldn't need a virtual network, so I did that.  Each machine could ping the other, but with I go in Explorer and click on Network, all I see is tsclient and there the other machine is not there.

So I created 2 more VMs, this time in separate services, but with a virtual network.  Again the machines can ping eachother base on the 192.168.... ip, but they don't show up on the network.

I already turned on "network discovery" for both, and I make the local network a "Work" network.

What do you have to do to get VMs in Azure so see each other on the network.  The app is supposed to refer to the database like \vmhost2\MSSQLEXPRESS  so I'm trying to get the vm to show up in the network, as a named host computer.

Comment: Assuming you mean the network browser, this has nothing to do with whether or not you can connect to a service like SQL server on another computer.

Comment: @RobM well but how can one vm know what the host name of another computer is?   can I just locate a server by \\192.168.0.5\SQLEXPRESS?  When they were both in the same service, I could actuall ping the other vm by hostname, though it would then resolve it to some longer string hostname.  But on separate services, how could I refer to the other computer by hostname.  And anyway I still don't know why I couldn't find the computer in the Network icon in Explorer.

Comment: 1) DNS. 2) yes. 3) Explorer, IIRC, only shows machines in the network share if they're on the same LAN and have file shares active

Answer (score -4):

Turn on Computer Browser for each box you want to see and they will show up in a few minutes.